# Dynamically Generate List of Pages in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, sorting

I have a list of pages that I want to list in the sidebar of my site. I have done it before with some posts and have used tags to automatically generate the list of links that have the specific tag. Since you can not add tags to pages, I am not sure what to use to group pages together and then dynamically generate the list of pages as a select menu in the sidebar. I thought about adding a class to each of the pages, but wasn't sure how that would work exactly. Any thoughts you guys have would be great.

Comment: so you want to know how to programmatically create a menu of the pages for the sidebar?  Or you want to know how to group them?

Comment: How to programmatically create the menu. To do this though I need to have a way that I have grouped all of the pages that should be included in the list. Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to group and sort them, I would look into creating a "Custom Taxonomy" structure. Smashing Magazine has a good article on them: http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/01/04/create-custom-taxonomies-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks Charlie. I will take a look at the article today and see if it works for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress itself doesn't support tagging pages likewise in posts. However you can do it by installing a plugin.
Check this link [TagPages](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tagpages/) 
This plugin allow you to tag your pages and you will get result like as shown in screenshot. Then you can fetch results on the basis of these tags. Hope this is what you need.

[image]